# Jenkins API with python

Tags: python, jenkins

I'm having some difficulties implementing the jenkins api with my python script. For example trying to add disable_job. I have my connection to jenkins working and can build jobs but disabling I can't

```
def disable_job(server, project):
    try:
        job_exists = server.get_job_name(project)  # check to see if job exists
        if job_exists == None:
            print 'Error: Project (job) %s does not exist.\n\n' % project
            ret = None
        else:
            server.disable_job(project)
            msg = ('Disabled project (job) %s\n' % project)
    except:
        emsg = ('Error: Something went wrong building project (job) %s on '
                'Jenkins.\n\n' % project)
        print emsg
    return disable_job
```

Comment: Your code is working fine.

Comment: @barney I tried running the code but it just doesn't seem to, To you nothing seems wrong? Maybe I have something wrong in my configuration

Comment: server.disable_job should takes a string as the parameter. Are you passing a string? Are you getting any error?

Comment: @Barney yes and there is no error message, just it doesnt disable any job

Comment: @Barney can you check my comment below to see how to figure the copy jenkins portion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import jenkins
server = jenkins.Jenkins('http://localhost:8080', username='', password='')

server.disable_job('job_name')
```

Comment: How about for copying a project? If I dont want to hardcode the from_name and to_name